# Error in VSPKnown(N, n, k, Pa = seq(0, 1, 0.001), Plots = TRUE)

Tags: r, error-handling, statistics, package, sampling

In the Dodge package , I think something is wrong with this command

`VSPKnown(N, n, k, Pa = seq(0, 1, 0.001), Plots = TRUE)`

In the documentation, it is written than Pa represents the fraction non conforming (although the notation says something else), however, when applying the function , I found that it is the probability of acceptance. In fact, this is not logical at all as it should be accepting the fraction non conforming. Is this an error?